# Mysql View (Last six month data)

Tags: mysql

Is there any possibility to create a view for last six month or any other duration.

Because I want to avoid each time query with 1 billion records

```
SELECT c.CONTACT_ID,c.CONTACT_EMAIL,l.MAPPING_TIME FROM ContactInformation as c INNER JOIN ListToContactMapping as l ON c.CONTACT_ID=l.CONTACT_ID LEFT JOIN ContactScoreByModule as cs ON c.CONTACT_ID=cs.CONTACT_ID WHERE  ((((((l.MAPPING_TIME >= 1519822800000) AND (l.MAPPING_TIME <= 1522504799000)) AND ((c.CONTACT_STATUS =  BINARY 'active') OR (c.CONTACT_STATUS =  BINARY 'softbounce'))) AND (l.LIST_ID = 5000000004001)) AND (l.STATUS =  BINARY 'subscribed')))  GROUP BY c.CONTACT_ID LIMIT 0,21;
```

Curerently we getting static query only

date column is in milliseconds.

```
+---------------+---------------------------+---------------+
| CONTACT_ID    | CONTACT_EMAIL             | MAPPING_TIME  |
+---------------+---------------------------+---------------+
| 5000000004052 | arunkumar.muthu+9@abc.com | 1520819541000 |
| 5000000004053 | arunkumar.muthu+8@abc.com | 1520819541000 |
| 5000000004054 | arunkumar.muthu+7@abc.com | 1520819541000 |
| 5000000004055 | arunkumar.muthu+6@abc.com | 1520819541000 |
| 5000000004056 | arunkumar.muthu+5@abc.com | 1520819541000 |
| 5000000004057 | arunkumar.muthu+4@abc.com | 1520819541000 |
| 5000000004058 | arunkumar.muthu+3@abc.com | 1520620200000 |
| 5000000004059 | arunkumar.muthu+2@abc.com | 1520620200000 |
+---------------+---------------------------+---------------+
```

Comment: Views are stored queries that when invoked produce a result set - in other words they query the data base on demand and ire not intrinsically faster than a query.

Comment: ... in fact, in MySQL, the ability of a view to utilise an index is so limited that they're almost useless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use DATE_SUB() to get last 6 months

```
 CREATE VIEW View_Name AS SELECT col1,col2,.... FROM Table_Name
 WHERE date_column > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
```

In MiliSecond

```
SELECT CONTACT_ID,CONTACT_EMAIL,
FROM_UNIXTIME(LEFT( MAPPING_TIME,length(MAPPING_TIME)-3)) AS Date
FROM Table1
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(LEFT( MAPPING_TIME,length(MAPPING_TIME)-3)) > 
DATE_SUB( FROM_UNIXTIME(LEFT( MAPPING_TIME,length(MAPPING_TIME)-3)), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
```

Check The Link

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/65f20d/12

Comment: for my case compare with milliseconds column, but you given a solution for date column.

Comment: Give your column names and sample data

Comment: This serves no practical purpose

Comment: @JayShankarGupta Please find my question now

Comment: Check the link @Aaryan